# How to convert a Java 8 Stream to an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

What is the easiest/shortest way to convert a Java 8 `Stream` into an array?

Comment: I'd suggest you to revert the rollback as the question was more complete and showed you had tried something.

Comment: @skiwi Thanks! but i thought the attempted code does not really add more information to the question, and nobody has screamed "show us your attempt" yet =)

Comment: @skiwi: Although I usually shout at the do-my-homework-instead-of-me questions, this particular question seems to be clearer to me without any additional mess. Let's keep it tidy.

Comment: You can find a lot of answers and guidance in the official docs of the package: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1619, accepted):

The easiest method is to use the `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` method with an array constructor reference. This is suggested in the [API documentation for the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

```
String[] stringArray = stringStream.toArray(String[]::new);
```

What it does is find a method that takes in an integer (the size) as argument, and returns a `String[]`, which is exactly what (one of the overloads of) `new String[]` does.

You could also write your own `IntFunction`:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = ...;
String[] stringArray = stringStream.toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

The purpose of the `IntFunction<A[]> generator` is to convert an integer, the size of the array, to a new array.

Example code:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
String[] stringArray = stringStream.toArray(size -> new String[size]);
Arrays.stream(stringArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: and here is an explanation why and how the Array constructor reference actually work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447561/how-do-java-8-array-constructor-references-work

Comment: *"Zenexer is right, the solution should be: stream.toArray(String[]::new);"* ... Well ok, but one should understand that the method reference is logically and functionally equivalent to `toArray(sz -> new String[sz])` so I'm not sure that one can really say what the solution should or must be.

Comment: The array constructor reference is more concise. The documentation for the `toArray()` method cites its concision and includes its use in the only example. When it was tacked on the end of the answer, I missed it on first reading. Moved it to the top, above the details, so that no one else will miss it.

Comment: @scottb `sz -> new String[sz]` makes a new function where as the constructor reference does not. It depends how much you value Garbage Collection Churn I guess.

Comment: @WORMSS It does not. It (statically!) makes a new, `private` *method*, which cannot cause churn, and *both* versions need to create a new object. A reference creates an object that points directly at the target method; a lambda creates an object that points at the generated `private` one. A reference to a constructor should still perform better for lack of indirection and easier VM optimization, but churning has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @HTNW you are correct, my apologise. It was infact my attempt to debug that was causing the churn that was causing the churn the first time I tried to do this, so I have had it stuck in my head that this is how it was. (Hate it when that happens).

Comment: "String[] stringArray = stringStream.toArray(size -> new String[size]);", where is the size come from?

Comment: Lambda should simplify things but  java lambda like `stream.toArray(size -> new String[size]);` just looks akward and this is so unintuitive every developer will forget this syntax the next time he needs an array. Why do they make things so complicated where c# is making life pretty easy with lambda. My stack is java but since years java getting more and more behind of c#.

Comment: Instead of `stream.toArray(size -> new String[size])`, you can shorten it using a method reference: `stream.toArray(String[]::new)`, which accomplishes the same thing. Syntactic sugar, if you have a sweet tooth.

Answer (score 66):

If you want to get an array of ints, with values from 1 to 10, from a `Stream<Integer>`, there is `IntStream` at your disposal.

Here we create a `Stream` with a `Stream.of` method and convert a `Stream<Integer>` to an `IntStream` using a `mapToInt`. Then we can call `IntStream`'s `toArray` method.

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
//or use this to create our stream 
//Stream<Integer> stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed();
int[] array =  stream.mapToInt(x -> x).toArray();
```

Here is the same thing, without the `Stream<Integer>`, using only the `IntStream`:

```
int[]array2 =  IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray();
```

Answer (score 34):

You can convert a java 8 stream to an array using this simple code block:

```
 String[] myNewArray3 = myNewStream.toArray(String[]::new);
```

But let's explain things more, first, let's  Create a list of string filled with three values:

```
String[] stringList = {"Bachiri","Taoufiq","Abderrahman"};
```

Create a stream from the given Array :

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Arrays.stream(stringList);
```

we can now perform some operations on this stream Ex:

```
Stream<String> myNewStream = stringStream.map(s -> s.toUpperCase());
```

and finally convert it to a java 8 Array using these methods:

1-Classic method (Functional interface)

```
IntFunction<String[]> intFunction = new IntFunction<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public String[] apply(int value) {
        return new String[value];
    }
};


String[] myNewArray = myNewStream.toArray(intFunction);
```

2 -Lambda expression

```
 String[] myNewArray2 = myNewStream.toArray(value -> new String[value]);
```

3- Method reference

```
String[] myNewArray3 = myNewStream.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Method reference Explanation:

It's another way of writing a lambda expression that it's strictly equivalent to the other.

Answer (score 18):

Convert text to String array where separating each value by comma, and trim every field, for example:

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.stream(line.split(","))          
                             .map(String::trim)
                             .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a stream of strings from list of strings
        Stream<String> myStreamOfStrings = List.of("lala", "foo", "bar").stream();

        // Convert stream to array by using toArray method
        String[] myArrayOfStrings = myStreamOfStrings.toArray(String[]::new);

        // Print results
        for (String string : myArrayOfStrings) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Try it out online: https://repl.it/@SmaMa/Stream-to-array

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the accepted answer?

Comment: @LongNguyen It's a  full example including an online replay scenario, not only a snippet.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom collector that convert a stream to array.

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, T[]> toArray( IntFunction<T[]> converter )
{
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen( 
                  Collectors.toList(), 
                  list ->list.toArray( converter.apply( list.size() ) ) );
}
```

and a quick use

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList( ..... );

String[] result = input.stream().
         .collect( CustomCollectors.**toArray**( String[]::new ) );
```

Comment: Why would you use this instead of [Stream.toArray(IntFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)?

Comment: I needed a collector to pass to the 2-arg `Collectors.groupingBy` so that I could map some attribute to arrays of objects per attribute value. This answer gives me exactly that. Also @DidierL.

Comment: Since Java 11 the _finisher_ in _collectingAndThen_ can be written as `list -> list.toArray(converter)` due to addition of [Collection.toArray​(IntFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction))

Answer (score 3):

Using the `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` method is indeed a very elegant and safe way to convert (or more correctly, collect) a Stream into an array of the same type of the Stream.

However, if the returned array's type is not important, simply using the `toArray()` method is both easier *and* shorter.
For example:

```
    Stream<Object> args = Stream.of(BigDecimal.ONE, "Two", 3);
    System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s!", args.toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

int[] arr=   stream.mapToInt(x->x.intValue()).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a stream of string elements

Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");


// convert the stream to arrays of strings

String[] stringArray = stringStream.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: What was wrong with all the other answers saying the same?

Answer (score -1):

```
     Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

     Integer[] integers = stream.toArray(it->new Integer[it]);
```