# Why do the new Java 8 streams return an Object Array on toArray calls?

Tags: java, java-8

Whilst I was working on a project involving Java 8's new streams, I noticed that when I called `Stream#toArray()` on a stream, it return an `Object[]` instead of a `T[]`. Surprised as I was, I started digging into the source code of Java 8 and couldn't find any reason why they didn't implement `Object[] toArray();` as `T[] toArray();`. Is there any reasoning behind this, or is it just an (in)consistency?

EDIT 1:
I noticed in the answers that a lot of people said this would not be possible, but this code snippet compiles and return the expected result?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test<R> {

    private Object[] items;

    public Test(R[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public R[] toArray() {
        return (R[]) items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> integerTest = new Test<>(new Integer[]{
            1, 2, 3, 4
        });

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integerTest.toArray()));
    }

}
```

Comment: How would it know `R`? If you want specific types to be returned, pass a generator to the method. For example for a String array, do the following: `streamString.toArray(String[]::new)`

Comment: `R` is the type parameter of the Stream interface. I used `R` in my question, but it should be `T`. Will update that.

Comment: @meskobalazs But still, worst case scenario, you could cast it to the desired type. Why did they choose to go the wildcard path instead of the typed path? I feel sometimes, that it is unknown to the programmer what type stream has so having to case it, doesn't make for the best code. And the stream is still the one that knows exactly what type it contains.

Comment: You wouldn't know to which type you should cast, because at runtime Java doesn't know the actual type, because of the *type erasure* (just as it stands in the answer of @Susei)

Comment: But it's possible? `R[] toArray() { return (R[]) new Object[0]; }`

Comment: An `Object[]` is not necessarily a `R[]`. That cast is bound to fail at runtime.

Comment: Object does not extends `R`, so this will throw a `RuntimeException`

Comment: It is in this case. A stream can only consist of one type, so in this case the type must be `R[]`. There is no exception.

Comment: @meskobalazs We are casting objects that most certainly extend `R`.

Comment: The cast to `R[]` should be your warning sign.  This is an _unchecked_ cast, and the compiler tells you so (but you probably just ignored this).  `items[]` is *not* an array of `R[]`, so the compiler is quite right to say that it can't verify this cast -- and it can't stop a client from casting the returned array to `Object[]`, and then putting non-R values in it, which would subvert the supposed type-safety of saying "this is an array of R".

Comment: Note that there's also a `toArray` method that takes an array factory, which you can call as `String[] arr = stream.toArray(String[]::new)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same problem that `List#toArray()` has. Type erasure prevents us from knowing the type of array we should return. Consider the following

```
class Custom<T> {
    private T t;
    public Custom (T t) {this.t = t;}
    public T[] toArray() {return (T[]) new Object[] {t};} // if not Object[], what type?
}

Custom<String> custom = new Custom("hey");
String[] arr = custom.toArray(); // fails
```

An `Object[]` is **not** a `String[]` and therefore cannot be assigned to one, regardless of the cast. The same idea applies to `Stream` and `List`. Use the overloaded `toArray(..)` method.

Comment: Look at my edit. Could you explain why this works then?

Comment: Your code is fine because `items` is actually an `Integer[]`, not an `Object[]` that has been cast to something else.

Comment: @MartijnRiemers In your example, you are returning the array you already created (for which you know the type). A `Stream` (or a `List`) is not guaranteed to be backed by an array. It can be constructed by any other means. This means that a **new** array has to be created, but we can't know which type.

Comment: It still feels a bit weird but your casting example makes a lot of sense. Accepted as the answer.

Comment: Digging further in, why does ArrayList return an `Object[]` while the underlying array of items is of type `E[]`? I came across this one whilst I was looking at `Stream#collect(Collectors#toList()).toArray()`.

Comment: @MartijnRiemers The real (runtime) type of the `ArrayList`'s underlying array is `Object[]`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Maybe, it's just me, but I feel this is one of the most confusing parts of Java. Wouldn't it make more sense to have the class of the generic type to call on e.g. `R.class.cast()`, making generics a whole lot more useful.

Comment: @MartijnRiemers They made the decision to implement generics with type erasure. There's a lot of discussion online about whether this was a good choice or a bad one. You might want to look into them. It's currently impossible to do things like `R.class` when `R` is a type variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see multiple packages using the `Class<R> clazz`trick nowadays. These are the parts where .NET wins it over Java.

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
String[] = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(Object::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

The no-arg toArray() method will just return an Object[], but if you pass an array factory (which can be conveniently represented as an array constructor reference), you can get whatever (compatible) type you like.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly address OP's question, this is the answer I was searching for.

Answer (score 5):

About the reason why `toArray()` returns `Object[]`: it is because of type erasure. Generic types lose their type parameters at runtime so `Stream<Integer>`, `Stream<String>` and `Stream` become the same types. Therefore there is no way to determine component type of array to create. Actually, one could analyze types of array's elements using reflection and then try to find their [least upper bound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4), but this is too complicated and slow.

There is a way to get `R[]` array by using overloaded [`toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method. This method gives the caller an opportunity to choose type of the array. See this SO question for code examples: [How to Convert a Java 8 Stream to an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079003/convert-stream-to-array).