# How do Java 8 array constructor references work?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, method-reference

Say we have a variable of type `IntFunction` that returns an integer array:

```
IntFunction<int[]> i;
```

With Java 8 generics, it is possible to initialize this variable with a constructor reference like this:

```
i = int[]::new
```

How does the Java compiler translate this to bytecode?

I know that for other types, like `String::new`, it can use an `invokedynamic` instruction that points to the String constructor `java/lang/String.<init>(...)`, which is just a method with a special meaning.

How does this work with arrays, seeing that there are special instructions for constructing arrays?

Comment: In Java, these are called references, not pointers.  Generally references provide nearly all the operations of pointer, except that you can not add an arbitrary offset to a reference, or perform other kinds of math operations on them.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can find out yourself by decompiling the java bytecode:

```
javap -c -v -p MyClass.class
```

The compiler desugars array constructor references `Foo[]::new` to a lambda (`i -> new Foo[i]`), and then proceeds as with any other lambda or method reference.  Here's the disassembled bytecode of this synthetic lambda:

```
private static java.lang.Object lambda$MR$new$new$635084e0$1(int);
descriptor: (I)Ljava/lang/Object;
flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: iload_0       
     1: anewarray     #6                  // class java/lang/String
     4: areturn
```

(It's return type is Object because the erased return type in IntFunction is Object.)