# Instantiating array of objects with streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, instantiation, java-stream

I have an array of ints that I want to use to instantiate a array or list of objects.  In my case, the old-fashoned way to do it would be:

```
int[] layer_sizes = {784, 500, 10};
Layer[] layers = new Layer[layer_sizes.length];
for (int i=0; i<layer_sizes.length; i++)
    layers[i] = new Layer(layer_sizes[i]);
```

But now I see Java 8 has all these fancy streams.  I now want to do something like Python's list comprehensions:

```
List<Layer> layers = Stream.of(layer_sizes).map(size -> Layer(size));
```

But it doesn't let me do that, and I'm not sure why... The message it gives is

```
incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream<R> comforms to List<Layer> where R, T are type variables....
```

Is there a way to use Streams to construct an array of objects in one line?

EDIT: Not a duplicate of previous question, because it turns out that there're some peculiarities of making streams from primitives.

## Conclusion

Thank you Sam Sun and Eran.  The line I ended up using was this:

```
Layer[] layers = Arrays.stream(layer_sizes).boxed().map(Layer::new).toArray(Layer[]::new);
```

Whatever boxed() is, you need it, unless you declare layer_sizes as an `Integer` instead of `int`.

**P.S.** If the java developers are reading this, it would be amazing for Java 9 or whatever's next to have something like

```
Layer[] layers = {new Layer(size) for (size:layer_sizes)}  // OR at least:
Layer[] layers = Stream.of(layer_sizes).map(Layer::new).toArray()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert a Java 8 Stream to an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079003/how-to-convert-a-java-8-stream-to-an-array)

Comment: Similar: http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/convert-stream-to-array-in-java-8/

Comment: For future reference, `boxed` converts the IntStream, a class for providing a stream of `ints`, to an instanceof the interface `Stream` with a type of `Integer`. Basically, you're going from a stream of `int` to a stream of `Integer`, and you need that because generics behave weirdly with primitive types (and especially arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eran's answer has the general idea of what to do, but is missing a few key details.

Using `Stream.of` on an `int[]` will result in a `Stream<int[]>`; one of the magical artifacts of Java.

Instead, you should use `Arrays.stream` or `IntStream.of` to get a `IntStream` (remember, primitives can't be a parameter).

For the `map` operation, you can use a method reference to `Layer::new`.

This all boils down to this new snippit

```
List<Layer> layers = IntStream.of(layer_sizes).boxed().map(Layer::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Bingo.  I miss Python.

Comment: Why not `mapToObj` instead of `boxed().map`?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing two things - collecting the Stream into a List and invoking the `Layer` constructor (you are missing the `new` keyword) :

```
List<Layer> layers = 
    IntStream.of(layer_sizes)
             .mapToObj(size -> new Layer(size))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you wish your output to be an array instead of a `List`, call `toArray` instead of `collect`.

EDIT :

I just realized that `Stream.of`, when passed an `int[]`, would produce a `Stream<int[]>`, not a `Stream<Integer>`. Therefore, you should use `IntStream`, which handles primitive `int` elements.

The alternative is to replace the input `int[] layer_sizes = {784, 500, 10};` with `Integer[] layer_sizes = {784, 500, 10};`.

Comment: Thanks... my bad on forgetting new... but it still doesn't work.  I'm now getting the error `Inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Layer, lower bounds: Object`

Comment: @Peter What did you try? `collect` or `toArray`? If `toArray()`, try `toArray(Layer[]::new)`.

Comment: Both.  `toArray(Layer[]::new)` almost worked but now oddly, it complains about the "size" variable being fed into Layer, saying `int[] cannot be converted into int`.  I don't see why it should think size is an int[].

Comment: @Peter Oh, I see the problem now. Your `int[]` is converted to a `Stream<int[]>` and not `Stream<Integer>`. You can either use an `Integer[]`, or use `IntStream.of` and `mapToObj`.