# Using filter in streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
String[] arr={"121","4545","45456464"};
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(s->s.length()>4).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Can someone tell me exactly *what's happening with* `toArray(String[]::new)` in above code snippet.

Comment: So, is this question about `filter` or about `toArray`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert a Java 8 Stream to an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079003/how-to-convert-a-java-8-stream-to-an-array)

Answer (score 5):

`String[]::new` is actually the same as `size -> new String[size]`.
A new `String[]` is created with the same size as the number of elements after applying the [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). See also the javadoc of [`Stream.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)

Answer (score 3):

The `toArray` is creating a `String[]` containing the result of the `filter` in your case all strings whose length is greater than 4. The `filter` returns a `Stream` and so you are converting it into an array.

To print the filtered result rather than storing it into an array

```
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(s -> s.length() > 4).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: How to print that string?

Comment: Do you mean rather than storing it back to `String[]` or how to print an array in general. I updated the answer to show how you can print a stream

Comment: If the value  is stored in String as mentioned in question and what is the reference for that String and how to access it?

Comment: `String[]::new` is called constructor reference in java which is the same as `new String[size]` as explained in the other answer. `toArray` returns that array.

Comment: @vnyuppara if you want one String use `.collect(Collectors.joining(","))` using `toArray` returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

`String[]::new` is a reference to new operator of `String[]` type. It is Java-8 syntax. `toArray` method of `Streams` take an `IntFunction<A[]>` as the generator for the array in which elements of the stream will be collected. It is the same as writing:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).filter(s->s.length()>4).toArray(size-> { return new Integer[size]; });
```