# Convert String to HashMap<String,String[]>

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have Java Commandline App where I'm using parameters when starting the .jar file.
Parameters looks like

```
--exclude parent1=child1,child2;parent2=child3;parent3
```

I want to convert the parameters to `HashMap<String, String[]>` where the key=parent1 and value=[child1,child2]

I tried with Streams and split() function but I can't convert the child strings to Array of Strings

```
Arrays.stream(gotData.split(";"))
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1].split(",")));
```

Comment: Possibly related: [How to group into map of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695027/how-to-group-into-map-of-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your issue you have to check each time your data, because in the collect part you try to split `s[1]` for `parent3` which not exist, to avoid this issue, you can check the length of array before like so

```
Arrays.stream(gotData.split(";"))
    .map(s -> s.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> {
        // If there size of array great than 1 mean there are children.
        if (s.length > 1) {
            return s[1].split(",");
        }
        // Else just return an empty array.
        return new String[0];
    }));
```

If you have other cases, maybe you need to add other conditions to this code to avoid any kind of errors.

---

To show the response:

```
response.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " - " + Arrays.toString(v)));
```

**Otputs**

```
parent1 - [child1, child2]
parent3  - []
parent2 - [child3]
```

Comment: I am very fine ! And you   ? :)